# Generate link to download folder in S3

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have setup website where you can send files to Amazon S3 cloud storage. Multiple files can be stored in folders like so:

`my_bucket/folder1/file1.txt`

`my_bucket/folder1/file2.txt`

Now I am trying to generate link for user to download whole `folder1` which I found weirdly hard to do. Is there something I am missing? Trying to generate url using `getObjectUrl("mybucket", "folder1")` for `folder1` is giving me error.

Also is there a way I could make generated URL **not** to look like this:

`https://my_bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/file1.txt`

but something that is more appropriate for a general public usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S3 does not have this feature. You would need to zip up all the files you want to provide a link for, put the zip file on S3, and then generate a link to that.

Comment: Thank you.
And is there a way how to generate link that would be more publicly usable? As I mentioned in my question.

Comment: If you don't like the provided S3 domain names you can always map your own (sub)domain to an S3 bucket.