# How to enable Download all behavior for a large amount of links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3

we are currently sending our clients emails, with download links to the assets they have on s3. The problem is, when there is a large number of links, let's say 70, they have to click on each individual link to download the files. is there a way in Ruby on Rails to implement a 'Download All' functionality without downloading those files first?

Answer (score 1):

This feature of downloading all links is not part of ruby, and s3 doesn [not have folder dowload feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35482534/generate-link-to-download-folder-in-s3).
I think that, you can collect all files in one ZIP and share 70 + 1 link, so the extra link is the one pointing the zip File with all the downloads, notify this in the email. And this should fullfill your requirements

Comment: meaning, if we have 10 links to 1gb files, we should include link to a 10gb zip file?